# C#: Is there a way to resize an array of unknown type using reflection?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, resize

My users pass me an array of some type, say int[] or string[].  I can easily query the types of the elements via GetElementType, and I can find out how long the array was when it was passed to me via GetRank, GetLength, etc.

The arrays are passed in a params list, so visualize code like this:

```
    public void Resizer(params object[] objs)
    {
        foreach (object o in objs)
            Array.Resize(ref o, 3);
    }
```

What I would like to do is the converse of the Get methods that are available and that do work: I want to resize the array that was passed to me, setting the length to some other length (like 3 in this silly example).

I'm doing this because in my setting the array will contain data received from a set of cloud computing servers and we can't know how many will respond in advance, hence can't preallocate the array to have the right length.  Ideally, in fact, my user passes in an array of length 0, and I pass back an array of length n, signifying that I got n replies from the servers that were queries.

I can't do this with Array.Resize(ref T, int) because I don't know T at compile time.

Is there a way to pull this off?

Comment: Have you considered using a `List<T>` which is automatically resized when adding elements to it?

Comment: Why are your users passing you an array of questionable heritage? Why not use a specific type (using generics, for instance), or one of the dynamic data structures, like `List<T>`?

Comment: The type is completely dependent upon the service.  One might pass back images, another temperatures, another the count of people who asked similar questions in the past.  When your user works with a library that is itself defined using generics, as mine is, this is a common issue.

Comment: Darin, I've been considering that.  Definitely an option, but because it is inefficient to index into a List, not my first choice.  But I could do as you suggest and it would be my fallback

Comment: @Ken, *inefficient to index into a List*? A List uses an array internally so indexing a list is as efficient as indexing an array which is very efficient.

Comment: Guys, to reiterate.  I really do understand that I can do this with a list.  I really will do that if I can't do what I want to do.  So we can accept that that's an option.  I'm not questioning that option.  I'm asking if there is a way to do it the way I'm trying to do it.  So if you could just accept, as a kind of an academic thing, that we're thinking about this as a puzzle, it would be awesome to know if this puzzle can be solved WITHOUT switching to using a list, ok?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Indexing into a `List<someClassType>` is reasonably efficient.  Working with elements in a `List<someStructType>`, however, can be much less efficient than working with elements in a `someStructType[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is curious, I ended up switching my code to use List

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
static void Resize(ref Array array, int newSize) {        
    Type elementType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
    Array newArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, newSize);
    Array.Copy(array, newArray, Math.Min(array.Length, newArray.Length));
    array = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Don't see why this will work.  Does Array.Copy deal with resizing?  If so, that will solve my problem, thanks!  I'll try it

Comment: GetElementType() is much more elegant than my index of zero. +1

Comment: George, unclear how that connects to the code that was shown.  Obviously one uses GetElementType to get the type.  But you can't use GetElementType in Array<T>.Resize because T has to be specified using a static (compile-time) type, not a runtime type.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  This just doesn't work at all.  It doesn't even try to resize the old array.  Totally ignores what I'm trying to do.  I want the old array to have a new size.

Comment: @Ken: then simply assign `oldArray = newArray`

Comment: No, the problem then is that the caller has a different reference.  Caller presumably did something like Foo[] myFoos = new Foo[0].  Then callServers(...myFoos...).  Now I want myFoos to be an array of length 15.  Your scheme creates the array of length 15, but the caller ends up still having his old 0-length vector because inside my code I don't really have a ref to his variable (due to "params" not allowing that).  So if I can resize his actual Foo, I'm in good shape.  But anything that creates a new vector leaves me cooked.

Comment: Right, but can't combine ref with params.  They actually send me one or more of these things; in fact they send me the arguments to the RPC on the servers, then a kind of EOL marker, and then a list of these refs.  So can't use "ref" because that combines refs with params.  (Similarly, can't use out)

Comment: Well then, unless you return the new array as the method return parameter and tell the API users to assign the return parameter to their array, you can't do what you want. You can't arbitarily change a variable in another stack frame.

Comment: That's the conclusion I was coming to as well.

Comment: @Ken - you can't "change" the size of an array.  Once the size is set, it's immutable.  So, creating a new array with the new length is really your only option.  Have you considered returning an array in your method signature?  public object[] Resizer(params object[] objs);  That way you can still work with arrays, and your user would simply be expected to do something like:  object[] arr = Resizer(obj1, obj2, obj3);

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a new array of whichever type you need that is the size that you want? Then populate it from the array you want to resize, setting non existent values to some default.

Comment: I do that but for syntactic sugar reasons, in this particular case I wanted them to pass in "place holders".

Comment: PS: Think about the old C scanf; my situation is similar.  Scanf needed by-ref arguments and scanned stuff into them.  I'm trying to mimic that coding style for this particular interface; I wanted by-ref vectors and want to fill them in.  But (1) params won't let you send stuff in by ref (a restriction on params), and (2) don't know how long the vectors will be until I know how many servers responded!

Comment: @Ken if you're able to get objects rather than standard types they will be passed in by reference.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  So: they create a vector like, say, an int[0] or a Foo[0].  Pass it in.  I get 11 Foo objects back from the servers.  Now I want them to get an array Foo[15].  So want to do Array<Foo>.Resize(ref hisObject, len), but now am stuck: can't get the ref and Foo needs to be a compile-time, not a runtime type.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that you should be using List(Of T), but if you want to copy your array into a new array of the same type, you could do something like the following.

```
// Your passed in array.
object[] objs = new object[5] {1,2,3,4,5};

// Create an array of the same type.
Array a = Array.CreateInstance(objs[0].GetType(), objs.Length+3);

// Copy in values.
objs.CopyTo(a,0);
```

Comment: Can't pass that back out.  So yes, I could do this, but whatever they passed me will be unchanged.

Comment: Pass it back out? If you have a a List<Of T) as your signature, you can just pass List.ToArray() back out, once it's resized.

Comment: Guys, take my word on this.  I could use List but in this case it would look ugly to the end user.  So let's work with me for a second and take my word that what I really want to do is to work with a vector of some unknown type, ok?  I'm hearing you, but it would take a lot of typing to explain why a list is just not ideal in my situation.  So let's just view that as given?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll just switch to using Lists, but this is a shame; the code will be quite a bit messier looking and since my users are basically at the level of first-semester ugrads, each little thing will make their lives less good.  But I'm suspecting that you folks don't see a way to do this either.  Oh well....