# C# resize an array of unknown type

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Is there a way to resize an array of unknown type using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760083/c-is-there-a-way-to-resize-an-array-of-unknown-type-using-reflection)

Hi,

Is there a way to resize an array of unknown type? Please see sample code below.

```
object ReadArray()
{
    Type classType = Type.GetType(arrayItemName, true);
    object arr = Array.CreateInstance(classType, 0); // unknown length

    // read length from a stream
    ResizeArray(ref arr, length)
    // populate array items from stream

    // read length2 from  stream2
    ResizeArray(ref arr, length+length2)
    // populate array items from stream2

    return arr;
}

ResizeArray(ref object array, int n)
{
    Array arr = array as Array;
    Array.Resize(ref arr, n); // compile error! type can't be inferred
    array = arr;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `List<T>` which will automatically be resized when you add items to it?

Comment: I saw that post, it suggests using a List or create a new array instance everytime. I'm wondering if there is a better solution. I'm writing an api and caller expects an array.

Comment: Yes, the proposed solution creates a new array instance every time. But then, so does `Array.Resize`. The only difference is that the proposed solution does it explicitly, whereas `Array.Resize` does it behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the method linked above, you might try using reflection; something like this should work (even though I don’t think it would be better, faster, or anything):

```
static void ResizeArray(ref object array, int n)
{
    var type = array.GetType();
    var elemType = type.GetElementType();
    var resizeMethod = typeof(Array).GetMethod("Resize", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    var properResizeMethod = resizeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(elemType);
    var parameters = new object[] { array, n };
    properResizeMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
    array = parameters[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in another thread: [C#: Is there a way to resize an array of unknown type using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760083/c-is-there-a-way-to-resize-an-array-of-unknown-type-using-reflection)

Comment: I saw that post, it suggests using a List or create a new array instance everytime. I'm wondering if there is a better solution. I'm writing an api and caller expects an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot redimension the size of an array in C#. You can in VB and Vb.Net (if that helps).

Comment: @Dona: Using `Array.Resize` will also create a new array instance every time.

Answer (score -2):

```
Resize(ref object array, int size){
    object[] newarray = new object[size];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length&&i<size;i++){
        newarray[i] = array[i];
    }
    array = newarray;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong: 1. this does not resize anything (notice you are not using `size` at all…), 2. this unneccessarily copies the array _twice_.

Comment: sorry i was playing around and submitted answer before i was done. it has been fixed.

Comment: Not really, this does not compile (you cannot index `array[i]` as `array` is just an `object` (and you don’t know its type beyond `Array`, that’s the point of the question).